# I need to initialize something I really don't know previously what it is in Ruby

Tags: ruby, class

Let me try to explain what I need, then maybe someone may tell me how to do it.

I have a series of entities in my system. They are listed in an array

```
@entities = [ :component, :email, :form, :library, :page, :project, :resource, :template ]
```

I parse a command line using [Slop gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/slop), then I get all parsed options in the **opts** hash and the remaining command line parameters in the **args** array.

The first element of **args** array is always the entity I need to create to handle the command line inputs. Let's assume, for the sake of this reasoning, that I'm creating a **:project**.

Now, I have a file **project.rb**, which contains:

```
entity_block = lambda { |ent| 
  ent.entity_type = :project
  # All other initialization options
  .
  .
  .
}
```

And in my main module I have the following method:

```
def self.start(args,opts)

  # Saves arguments and options
  @arguments = args
  @options = opts

  # Isolates the entity which will handle the command line request
  @entity = @arguments[0]
  exit_error(103,@entites) if not @entities.include?(@entity.to_sym)

  # Requires the correct block for the entity type
  require "entities/#{@entity}"

  # Creates the entity class
  EmeraldFW::Entity.new(@arguments,@options) do 
    entity_block
  end
end
```

And here is my **entity.rb** file:

```
module EmeraldFW

  class Entity

    attr_accessor :entity_type, :entity_base_dir

    def initialize(args,opts)
      @args = args
      @opts = opts
    end

    def execute
      puts entity_base_dir
      puts "Do something..."
    end

  end

end
```

As you may see, what I intend to do is requiring among the `<entity_name>.rb` files, the file which contains the specific initial values for that specific entity.

The idea is having `entity_type`, for instance, initialized after running the code. Not just his, but all other parameters needed to identify that specific entity the user mentioned at the command line.

It happens that this is not working. If it were, I wouldn't be here bothering you, of course.

I tried do use `#tap` to inject the newly created Entity object in the lambda block defined by `entity_block`, like this:

```
EmeraldFW::Entity.new(@arguments,@options).tap do 
  entity_block
end
```

And I also tried to do `&entity_block` like this?

```
EmeraldFW::Entity.new(@arguments,@options).tap do 
  &entity_block
end
```

Summary: **My problem, then, is how to create an entity dinamically?**

Of course I considered the possibility of doing something like

```
entity_class = "EmeraldFW::#{@entity.capitalize}".split('::').inject(Object) {|o,c| o.const_get c}.new(@arguments,@options)
```

But first I'd like to know if this other way is possible and what I am missing here.

By the way, this is the error I always get:

```
/home/edvaldo/software/github/emeraldfw21/lib/emeraldfw.rb:34:in `block in start': undefined local variable or method `entity_block' for EmeraldFW:Module (NameError)
```

Comment: your examples passing entity_block to `tap` look fishy, can you be a little more explicit about what this is supposed to achieve? Are you trying to pass some object as the value of `self` in the block, or is the block passed an argument as a parameter?

Comment: I want to pass the newly created Entity object to the block in `entity_block`. It seems fishy to me either. I'm not sure this is the correct way to achieve what I need.

Comment: In a short way, what I need is to create an Entity object whose attributes are those of the entity mentioned in the command line.

Comment: I editted the question to explain a bit better, @maxpleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `entity_block` is a proc or lambda it won't be called if you just type it's name with out parenthesis (unlike a typical method, which will be called).

So I think your issue is that your block is never being called.

Try, instead, this:

```
entity = EmeraldFW::Entity.new(@arguments,@options)

entity_block.call(entity)

# similarly
entity.instance_eval { entity_block.call(self) }
```

By the way, regarding your use of `tap` - It looks like you're trying to achieve some dynamic scoping, which it won't do for you. It's really just syntactic sugar for assigning a variable, if you ask me. To get dynamic scoping for a block you can use `class_exec` or `instance_exec`. However doing this is unnecessary if you're explicitly passing around objects as arguments and aren't trying to redefine `self`.

Comment: It worked, but I don't really know what answer should I vote for, because I used both in the solution here.

Answer (score 1):

`entity_block` is a local variable in `project.rb`. A local variable can't survive through the `require`. You have to define either a constant (`ENTITY_BLOCK`), a module (`Entity`), an instance variable (`@entity_block`) or a global variable (`$entity_block`).

Of these, a module (or a class, as a special kind of module) would be best.

Comment: I understand. I'll try to do this. Thanks.

Comment: It worked, but I don't really know what answer should I vote for, because I used both in the solution here.